# Why hasn't Stack Overflow formed a "relationship" with jsFiddle yet?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, jsfiddle

The title explains it all.

You could then have an integrated interface, custom branding, in-page demos, etc. and I don't understand why it hasn't been done yet.

I know that similar questions have been asked before but I would like t know the reason that nothing has happened yet.

Comment: Dude, it's not even [status-planned].

Comment: Stack Exchange ended up doing [something of their own](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269753/feedback-requested-runnable-code-snippets-in-questions-and-answers) instead of relying on a third party website managed and operated by a single person. Correct decision in my opinion.